# How to add default text to CKEditor?

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor and I want ,when creating a new node, in the textarea of CKEditor to add some default text every time a user tries to create a new node.
How can I do that?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup a node field, there's a default value in the form.

Simply write down the default value there, and each time a new content is created, this field will be loaded with that default value.

[image]

Comment: @sokratis you're welcome, sometimes Drupal also makes life easy ;-) ...